# Why is it called linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question, terminology

For a system of linear equations in $\Bbb R^n$ to be linearly independent, there must be a unique solution to the system (at least I'm pretty sure that's true). There are definitely other definitions, but this is the one I am most used to.

Nonetheless, I am confused! Why should a set of vectors be called linearly independent under these circumstances? I mean, what are they independent of? Ultimately, I would like to know **why we use the terms linear dependence and independence?**

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If one of the vectors linearly *depended* on the others, then you would have infinite solutions. Having a set of linearly *independent* vectors implies that a unique solution exists

Comment: in $\mathbb R^{2}$ linearly  independent  vectors  are  not  along  the  same  line . May  be  that  has  something  to  do  with  the  name. Although  dimensional  spaces  the  linearly  independent vectors   are  not  lying  all  in  the  same  hyper-plane. Just  a  thought.

Comment: To me linearly independence is one of those math definitions that it is easier to get the feeling with characterisations (in this case something that isn't linearly dependent), rather than jumping into the definition itself. I find the definition of linearly dependence is intuitive enough. Often we need vectors that are NOT linearly dependent, and we call them linearly independent. There properties that characterise linearly independence, and many books use them as def. of linearly independence without using linearly dependence, which I find harder to get the feeling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have [**linear**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/linear) which is self-explanatory - 'of lines', and [**independence**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/independence?s=t) which means not reliant on each other, and the dictionary.com references the archaic definition [**competence**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/competence).

So a linearly independent set of vectors is a set of lines that competently (necessary and sufficient) defines a vector space.

> I mean, what are they independent of?

They are independent of each other.

Comment: Which definition of "competence" is relevant here? Your second paragraph appears to confuse "linearly independent set" for "basis".

Comment: @HenningMakholm; I read the question 'For a system of linear equations in $\mathbb{R^n}$ to be linearly independent' as implying we have $n$ (linearly independent) equations in $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Answer (score 6):

An expression of the form $a_1V_1 + a_2V_2 + ... + a_nV_n$ for vectors $V_i$ and scalars $a_i$ is called a "linear combination" because it generalizes the property that $y = ax$ is a line through the origin in the plane. It is simply a description that someone attached to the concept in the past, and is now common use.

A set of non-zero vectors are *linearly dependent* if at least one of them can be written as a linear combination of the others. It *depends* on the others. As such, you could kick that vector out as redundant, as everything that is a linear combination of the full set is also a linear combination of the other vectors without it.

A set of vectors is linearly independent if none of its vectors is a linear combination of the others. In this set, there are no redundant vectors. Throw out one, and you get a smaller span.

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that "linearly redundant set" would be a better, more descriptive label for what is called a "linearly dependent set."

Answer (score 2):

A different style of answer -

Imagine a space, in which lives our family of, say, four vectors.
Vector A and B or very independent, but C and D depend on each other - you could take C, and get D from him, or take D, and get C from him. More formally, one can be expressed from the other.

Imagine the space being ripped apart, and a part of it being taken away. If the ripping apart took away A and the space that supported him, then B can keep on existing. But if it took away the space that C lived in, D cannot live in this space anymore - a fundamental part of him was taken away.

So, in a way, D depends on the existence on C in the space. If the space cannot contain C, it cannot contain D, and vice versa. But A and B still remain expression-able in the space even if C and D do not.

this style of answer thinks of the space foremost and the list of vectors last, which is contrary to the usual mode of thought. But both are one and the same, depending on your current perception. so take whichever intuition helps you the most.

Cheers, and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The elements are *dependent* on each other if one term can be expressed in terms of the other terms. Otherwise, they are *independent* of each other.